# Wrong population of Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

Bonjour! The problem is that I cannot manage to populate my table view with data. Although it is correct in a way, I realized that the program puts one view over another again and again. Below, I provide pieces of code which are definitely related to the problem

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if cell.isHidden == true {

            cell.isHidden.toggle()

        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let record = records[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        let view = RecordView(price: record.price, place: record.place, time: record.date?.getDay(), category: record.category)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecordViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RecordViewCell

        cell.setRecordView(record: view)



        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear

        return cell



    }
```

Also,

```
class RecordViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    func setRecordView(record: RecordView) {

        view.addSubview(record)
        record.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 60)

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.isHidden = true
    }



}
```

[This is the link to the pic of how the table looks in general. There you can see that the shadows are overlapped and wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylXgK.png)

Thank you very much beforehand.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the image? I am not sure what is the expected behavior. That magic with `isHidden` is probably not necesary at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire `RecordView` should be created by the table. The fact that you are creating a new view every time you reuse a cell makes it impossible to reuse the views, which is the whole point of reusing cells.

However, as a fast fix, you have to always remove the previous view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

var record: RecordView? {
   didSet {
      oldValue?.removeFromSuperview()

      guard let record = record else { return } 

      view.addSubview(record)
      record.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 60)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of cells reusing, when you add subview to your cell this is not a new cell every time, sometimes it's reusing one.
In this case, much better to have record view as cell property and assign new record to this property. In this case you'll avoid multiple subviews here. 
Also, I don't actually understand why you hide cell in prepareForReuse, it's strange and unnecessary behavior.

```
class RecordViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var recordView: RecordView!

    func setRecordView(record: RecordView) {

        recordView = record

    }
}
```